# How to deal with a friend who cuts

Tags: abnormal-psychology, developmental-psychology, therapy

I am asking here since I have no idea where else I could of asked. I have a friend who is having difficulties with depression. I don't how long this has been ongoing, but he is often down. I presume it might of have been because he got rejected by the girl he liked. My friend often jokes about being in depression or suicide.

Today, we were walking outside and talking and my friend suddenly pulls up his sleeve and we (we were 3 other friends with him at that time) saw lots of cuts, around 15 of them, and one huge one in the middle (a very deep wound). He seemed *proud of showing off his cuts*, and bragged about the scar his big one would leave. We were quite shocked and did not know how to react. My other friend then confessed that he had seen the scars on a picture my friend sent him, but he thought it was a joke.

My friend has been seeing the school therapist for a while, but these scars were (presumably) from yesterday. I wonder if he is telling everything to this professional. I am a bit worried about my friend; that was a very deep wound.

I would like to have some tips on how to deal with a situation like this. He is seeing professional help, but I don't know if it is helping.

Answer (score 1):

Although popular culture and public opinion may lead people to believe that self injury is either a phase or people seeking attention. The truth is that this behavior becomes an unhealthy coping mechanism for any number of unpleasant scenarios.

The idea of distractionary coping mechanisms by themselves are not harmful, but self injury is specifically more dangerous because causing injury in the first place opens ones self up to infection, permanent physical damage, even accidental suicide.

Self injury often co-occurs with another mental illness, both disorders need to be diagnosed and treated by a decent psychiatric team which may include medications, but most definitely therapy. This is much more than a school therapist can provide. There is more information here: [Mayo Clinic on Self Injury](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/self-injury/home/ovc-20165425)

If your friend is not receiving the level of help that he needs or he cannot commit to safety, it would be best to take some type of action.

Possibly:

- Call a help line
- Inform the school therapist
- If your friend has any supportive family members, maybe informing them would help
- In any immediate emergency call 911